# Attempt to invoke virtual method null reference object

Tags: java, android

I ran this app on my phone just fine and then, after changing nothing, I changed out to install on my nexus 7. Now I am receiving this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.th3ramr0d.tc3studyguide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
```

This is the code at line 37.

```
rateMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

This is the entire block of code for the setOnClickListener

```
Button rateMe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rateMe);
rateMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.th3ramr0d.app"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

XML File

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/rateMe"
        android:text="Rate Me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

This worked just fine on my phone. I then tried to install it on my phone and it gives me the exact same error now. I have tried:

Gradle Sync

Rebuild app

Clean app

Uninstalled app on phone and tablet

Restarted both devices

Restarted Android Studio

Restarted computer

OnCreate Method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    boolean firstTimeRun = getFirstTimeRun();

    if (firstTimeRun == true) {
        firstTimeRun();
    } else {
        run();
    }


    Button rateMe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rateMe);
    ImageView prt = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prt);
    ImageView pfp = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pfp);

    rateMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.th3ramr0d.tc3studyguide"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    prt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.th3ramr0d.prtmanagerfree"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    pfp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.th3ramr0d.poundforpoundfree"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set your content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
```

Comment: nope only one xml file.

Comment: Ok, so please post onCreate

Comment: Not sure how that disappeared but after putting it back in it still isn't working. Exact same error.

Comment: Did you put it right after  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);? If so, try to clean the project and run it again.

Comment: Yup right below it. Cleaned the project and still nothing.

Comment: That did it. The clean didn't work the first time. I restarted Android Studio, did another clean, and now it's working again. I don't remember removing that line of code but then again I am extremely tired. Probably did it absent mindlessly. Thanks for the catch!